# Trouble Starting GridDB Service

Tags: linux, database, nosql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

I'm encountering difficulties starting the GridDB service on my system. I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux on my Windows 11 PC. When attempting to initiate the service using:

```
sudo systemctl start gridstore
```

I'm receiving an the below error message:

```
Job for gridstore.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status gridstore.service" and "journalctl -xeu gridstore.service" for details.
```

While viewing the details as suggested, t

```
└─$ sudo systemctl status gridstore.service
× gridstore.service - GridDB database server.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-09 18:12:57 +0545; 7min ago
    Process: 271 ExecStart=/usr/griddb/bin/gridstore start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]: ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU'
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: Stopping gridstore service:
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[324]: A80101: Node is not joined.
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: Stopped.
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: F01002: Startnode error
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: [ FAILED ]
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 systemd[1]: Failed to start GridDB database server..

└─$ sudo journalctl -xeu gridstore.service
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]:   File "/usr/bin/gs_startnode", line 133, in <module>
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]:     serverPid = util.getpid(pidfile)
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]:                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]:   File "/usr/griddb-5.3.0/bin/util.py", line 191, in getpid
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]:     fp = open(path, 'rU')
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[288]: ValueError: invalid mode: 'rU'
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: Stopping gridstore service:
Jan 09 18:12:56 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[324]: A80101: Node is not joined.
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: Stopped.
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: F01002: Startnode error
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 gridstore[271]: [ FAILED ]
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit gridstore.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit gridstore.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 09 18:12:57 DESKTOP-MADJTO2 systemd[1]: Failed to start GridDB database server..
░░ Subject: A start job for unit gridstore.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit gridstore.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 398 and the job result is failed.
```

I have followed the documentation from GridDB official website (https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/wsl/#running-griddb-on-wsl).

After the error had occured, I tried installing again in a new system with same configuration(WSL), but still same error is being seen.

Comment: AFAIK the possibility to use the 'U' flag for opening files was removed with python version 3 (or sometime in the process). Might be necessary that you explicitly start the whole thing with an older python, most likely the latest python 2. For a test, you can try running the command `x=open("/dev/zero", "rU")` in your `python`.

Answer (score 1):

for some installations of WSL, systemd is not available, which I suspect is happening to you. In the docs you linked to, there is a section for starting GridDB without systemd: https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/wsl/#using-griddb-on-wsl-without-systemd

Can you try that and see if it runs?